# Largest weakly connected component in networkX

Tags: python, graph, networkx, centralized

I have two questions.

1. In undirected graph, I want to find the largest connected component.
   And I read the API documents of networkX, finding this function
   `nx.connected_component_subgraphs()`. But I don't know how to use it, since its return value is a generator and I cant derive a subgraph of largest connected component.
2. It is same as one. But the graph is directed. And I want to find the largest weakly connected component of directed graph. Therefore, I use `nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs()`, this function. There has a same problem in question 1.

How can I use the built-in function in networkX to find the largest connected component in undirected graph and the largest weakly connected component in directed graph?

I use NetworkX 1.9.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The NetworkX component functions return Python generators. You can create a list of items in the generator using the Python `list` function.  Here is an example showing that and also finding the largest weakly connected component.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.DiGraph()

In [3]: G.add_path([1,2,3,4])

In [4]: G.add_path([10,11,12])
```

You can use e.g. list to turn the generator into a list of subgraphs:

```
In [5]: list(nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs(G))
Out[5]: 
[<networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph at 0x278bc10>,
 <networkx.classes.digraph.DiGraph at 0x278ba90>]
```

The max operator takes a key argument which you can set to the Python function `len` which calls len(g) on each subgraph to compute the number of nodes.  So to get the component with the largest number of nodes you can write

```
In [6]: largest = max(nx.weakly_connected_component_subgraphs(G),key=len)

In [7]: largest.nodes()
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [8]: largest.edges()
Out[8]: [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

Comment: looks like this doesn't work, likely from networkx 2.1 on. You just get a Set instead of a digraph, so you no longer have .nodes() available :(

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the solution offered no longer works since `weakly_connected_component_subgraphs` has been deprecated on networkx.

**TLDR:** use `subgraph(original_graph, weakly_connected_component_set)`

Instead of using an older version of networkx, it's possible to get the largest weakly connected component by doing the following:

```
#create an example graph
import networkx as nx
G = nx.lollipop_graph(10, 5)
G = G.to_directed() #weakly connected component needs a directed graph.
```

You can collect all of the weakly connected subgraphs or you can select the maximum subgraph by doing the following:

```
#list of all weakly connected subgraphs, each one is a set. 
#If you don't list them, you'll get a generator.
list_of_subgraphs = list(nx.weakly_connected_components(G))

list_of_digraphs = []

for subgraph in list_of_subgraphs:
    list_of_digraphs.append(nx.subgraph(G, subgraph)) #this is the relevant part.
```

Each one of those subgraphs will now be an nx digraph stored in `list_of_digraphs`.

If you want the max weakly connected subgraph,

```
max_wcc = max(nx.weakly_connected_components(G), key=len)
max_wcc = nx.subgraph(G, max_wcc)
```